# VB.NET For each exception on custom controls

Tags: vb.net, exception, for-loop, each

in VB.NET i have 2 custom controls, one is a TextBox and second one is a ComboBox.
These have custom values like Bool _IsHidden and are added on runtime to a form.

Now, at some point in the code I want to check if the _IsHidden is set to True or False and display that information. Since the user can edit this values when creating the control these are not set on creation.

So what I tried is:

(all of this is on MDI Forms)

```
For Each frm as CustomForm in Main.MdiChildren
If frm.MyName = calledBy Then 'this part is just to know which form called the form to create the object
For Each cntrl as CustomTextBox in frm.Controls
'DO Something
Next
End if
Next
```

Now.. if the first control is a custom ComboBox it thorws an error since it sees that it does not match the custom TextBox control..

how do i get around this? By my understanding it should just go through all of the controls on the said form and just check those who match CustomTextBox control ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`For Each x As T In collection` does *not* filter your collection items to those of type `T`. It tries to convert *every* item in `collection` to `T` and throws an exception if that fails.

Thus, you have the following options:

1. Do the check yourself, for example, using the code provided by [RB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8443091/87698).
2. Alternatively, you could filter your list *first*, and then loop through the items. Here, LINQ can help:

   ```
   For Each cntrl In frm.Controls.OfType(Of CustomTextBox)()
       ... ' Do this for all CustomTextBoxes
   Next

   For Each cntrl In frm.Controls.OfType(Of CustomComboBox)()
       ... ' Do this for all CustomComboBoxes
   Next
   ```

   You don't need the `As CustomTextBox` clause here, since [`frm.Controls.OfType(Of CustomTextBox)()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable(Of CustomTextBox)`, so `For Each` can infer by itself that `cntrl` must be of type `CustomTextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

> By my understanding it should just go through all of the controls on
>   the said form and just check those who match CustomTextBox control ?

That's not correct I'm afraid. You'll need to implement that check yourself, e.g:

```
For Each cntrl as object in frm.Controls
    If TypeOf cntrl Is CustomTextBox Then
        With CType(cntrl, CustomTextBox)
            .DoSomethingWithControl()
            .DoSomethingElseWithControl()
        End With
    End If 
Next
```